# How to have TODO list in the Lock-screen of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications

I invented a smart idea! I want to have a todo list as a lock-screen on my iPhone like grocery store listing to my lock-screen. Never forget to buy that dxmn toothpaste again :P

**How can I have a grocery store listing or todo listing on my lock-screen on iPhone?**

Comment: I found an app [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-info-lock-screen-reminders/id683108563?mt=8), I find it very very ODD if Apple Reminders app cannnot be used like this?! Is this incorporated in iOS as a basic feature?!

Comment: take a screenshot and make it a lock screen

Comment: @Buscar웃 it is not automatic! Lock Info is automatic and testing...looks awesome, not sure whether any better app than this, researching.

Comment: oh, I see, it has to be automated :)

Answer (score 1):

U can use [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com) or [Clear](http://realmacsoftware.com/clear/). If you install one of these apps there will be a widget in the notification center. Just drag down the notification center on your lock screen and you will see your to-do-list from one of these apps..

You can also use Apple's Reminders, these will also display in the notification center..